# Wikidata API always returns a Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, wikidata-api

I am using wikidata api to fetch a entity using its english title,

```
wdf = WikibaseDataFetcher.getWikidataDataFetcher();
eid = wdf.getEntityDocumentsByTitle("enwiki", entitle);
```

Earlier, with an older version of wikidata-api, I was able to run it smoothly.
After updating to version 5.0.0, I always get the following error,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.wikidata.wdtk.wikibaseapi.ApiConnection.fillCookies(ApiConnection.java:544)
    at org.wikidata.wdtk.wikibaseapi.ApiConnection.sendRequest(ApiConnection.java:346)
    at org.wikidata.wdtk.wikibaseapi.WbGetEntitiesAction.wbGetEntities(WbGetEntitiesAction.java:187)
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I get the same problem. 
I tried to use latest version from github and get the same exception. 
I execute the sample from documentation i.e the simple call:

```
Map<String, EntityDocument> results = wbdf.getEntityDocuments("Q80", "P31");
```

Seems code doesn't check for existence of a given cookie. 
I added the verification, recompiled and everything seems to work.

Go to ApiConnection.java:543

```
if (headerCookies != null)
    for (String cookie : headerCookies) {
```

No warranty ! :-)

Comment: This works. But I would really like someone to fix this in the api.

Comment: One of the devs submitted this fix in https://github.com/Wikidata/Wikidata-Toolkit/pull/218